# How to run my Summ.R file in to Rshiny app.R

Tags: r, rshiny

1. How to run my Summ.R file into R shiny app. I have created Summ.R and app.R. The Summ.R which actually creates data frame, I want this to be red using Rshiny app. But currently, it gives me an error, How to fix this error to get this dataframe viewed in Rshiny app.
2. Please share any resources to learn how to incorporate regular R scripts into Rshiny app.

**Summ.R**

```
data <- data.frame(
  SSN = c(204,401,101,666,777), 
  Name=c("Blossum","Buttercup","Bubbles","MojoJojo","Professor"), 
  Age = c(7,8,6,43,56), 
  Gender = c(0,0,0,1,1)
)

data
```

**output**

```
> data
  SSN      Name Age Gender
1 204   Blossum   7      0
2 401 Buttercup   8      0
3 101   Bubbles   6      0
4 666  MojoJojo  43      1
5 777 Professor  56      1
```

**Rshiny**

**app.R**

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  fluidPage(
    dataTableOutput("data")),
  function(input, output, session){
    source('R/Summ.R', local = TRUE)
    output$data <- renderDataTable(data)
  }
)
```

**Error**

```
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
```

Comment: Can Someone look at this question

Comment: Your code does not give me any error, the data dataframe is well rendered. Did you put your Summ.R file in the R folder as stated in the `source()` function? If your app.R and Summ.R files are located in the same folder, you can use `source('Summ.R')`. See [this tutorial](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson5/).